# My buttons wont appear on the screen for some reason in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My buttons wont appear  on the screen for some reason in Corona SDK here is my code what am I missing?

local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

-- include Corona's "widget" library
local widget = require "widget"

-- Function to handle button events
local function handleButtonEvent( event )

```
if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
    print( "Button was pressed and released" )
end
```

end

---

-- forward declarations and other locals
local playBtn

-- 'onRelease' event listener for playBtn
local function onPlayBtnRelease()

```
-- go to levelSelect.lua scene
composer.gotoScene( "levelSelect", "fade", 500 )

return true -- indicates successful touch
```

end

-- Background
 local sky = display.newImage ("startScreen/sky.png")
 sky.x = display.contentWidth/2; sky.y = display.contentHeight/2;

-- Picture
 local preston = display.newImage ("startScreen/PrestonArt.png")
preston:scale( 0.4, 0.4 )
preston.x = display.contentWidth/2; preston.y = display.contentHeight/2;

-- Labels
local learningLabel = display.newImage ("startScreen/Learning.png")
learningLabel:scale( 0.3, 0.3 )
learningLabel.x = 506; learningLabel.y = 170;

local centerLabel = display.newImage ("startScreen/Center.png")
centerLabel:scale( 0.3, 0.3 )
centerLabel.x = 506; centerLabel.y = 600;

function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

```
-- Called when the scene's view does not exist.
-- 
-- INSERT code here to initialize the scene
-- e.g. add display objects to 'sceneGroup', add touch listeners, etc.

-- create a widget button (which will loads levelSelect.lua on release)
playBtn = widget.newButton{
    defaultFile = "startScreen/Play.png",       --the "default" image file
    overFile = "startScreen/Play-Over.png",     --the "over" image file 
    width=240, height=120,
    onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease    -- event listener function
}
playBtn.x = 300; playBtn.y = 695;

-- all display objects must be inserted into group
 sceneGroup:insert( playBtn )
```

end

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

```
if phase == "will" then
    -- Called when the scene is still off screen and is about to move on screen
elseif phase == "did" then
    -- Called when the scene is now on screen
    -- 
    -- INSERT code here to make the scene come alive
    -- e.g. start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
end
```

end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

```
if event.phase == "will" then
    -- Called when the scene is on screen and is about to move off screen
    --
    -- INSERT code here to pause the scene
    -- e.g. stop timers, stop animation, unload sounds, etc.)
elseif phase == "did" then
    -- Called when the scene is now off screen
end
```

end

function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

```
-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (sceneGroup)
-- 
-- INSERT code here to cleanup the scene
-- e.g. remove display objects, remove touch listeners, save state, etc.

if playBtn then
    playBtn:removeSelf()    -- widgets must be manually removed
    playBtn = nil
end
```

end

---

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

---

return scene

Answer (score 2):

My guesses are

1. Comment says go to level1.lua but it tries to go to levelSelect
2. Don't use upper case in file names (in general)
3. try removing "fade", 500 to see it it works
4. in levelselect.lua you did not return scene or did not handle scene:create

More code and info please